# SQLite Equivalent to INTERVAL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to translate the PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE last_check_timestamp + (INTERVAL '1 seconds')*interval_seconds <= now()
```

to an equivalent query in SQLite.

What I'm getting stuck on is how to dynamically create dates/intervals based on table columns. What's the equivalent to "INTERVAL" in SQLite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for SQLite.  You can say this to add 1 second to a datetime value for instance:

```
select datetime(last_check_timestamp, '+1 second')
```

A full implementation of your example query might look something like this:

```
select * from mytable
where datetime(last_check_timestamp,
         '+' || interval_seconds || ' second') <= datetime('now','localhost');
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/lbp3G